# Where can I find the algorithm of prediction dynamics of a 2d uninterrupted function?

Tags: probability, geometry, functions, algorithms

1. **Given**

I have a uninterrupted function in 2D space. This function is given to me as discrete values. I can get an every value of the function in the given interval.
(*Moreover* I know some other functions, defined in the given interval and very like the new one, this knowledge I must use also)

```
   y
   ^
   |      _      /\__
   |     / \    /    \  ? ? ?  v
---+----|---\--/------|--------|-------> x
   0    a    \/       b        c
```

2. **My task**

I need to predict the value of function in the end of the next interval, the length of which less then length of given interval. I do *not need to find the exact value*, which this function will equals to. I just need to *find an approximate region* with big probability the function will be.

(The function is a trajectory of hand moving. The result of prediction is a position of a hand in the end of moving. This is a intermediate result to find a big region. Where I will use other algorithms of result correction and so on. So I plan to use the tens of points and re-calculate regularly to get more precise result as close to end of moving.)

3. **My research** in this task shows, that

methods of extrapolation (that based on interpolation methods (like cubic splines)) are not useful in this case, because they try to predict the value of a function using values only in a border, their prediction is valid only in a little E-vicinity.

In matlab there is *a prediction function*, which do what I want, but I can't find the algorithm it works. It is a first possible way, I can see.
The second way is, the prediction in *financial analysis* is that thing what I need. How they can see the future of *currency rate*? (*Moreover* item is very similar to a currency rate in last year corresponding the currency rate in this year)

4. **The question**

I need the links (or titles) to good books in algorithms of financial analysis prediction (because I am not a specialist in economics) or source of matlab prediction function.
Or your good ideas ;)

Comment: The method depends on 1. what assumption do you have about the function (can you model it somehow) 2. how much of the past and present information will be used with what influence to come up with a prediction. Here is some interesting book: ([link](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/haskell-financial-data-modeling-and-predictive-analytics))

Comment: The function is a trajectory of hand moving. The result of prediction is a position of a hand in the end of moving. This is a intermediate result to find a big region. Where I will use another algorithm of moving corrections and so on. So I plan to use the tens of points and re-calculate regularly to get more precise result as close to end of moving.